# Downloading App Source Code From Apple Dev and Google Dev

Tags: ios

We have hired a developer for creating apple and android app for our website. Our apps are also live and we have access to Apple and Google play developer accounts! *But we don't have source code and we lost connection with our developer!*

We want the source code very, very, badly!

Is there any way to download it from the Apple and Google play developer accounts?

Hoping there will be some or some other way!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: There might be some valid reason why you cannot request code from developer to whom you paid :p

Comment: Ouch! Looks like an expensive business lesson…

Comment: @adnan No, We bought the source code rights. The developer closed his business and doesn't respond!

Comment: Hmm lesson instead of code . Bad luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the app and decompile then but you will never be able to get the original source code. The reason being that both Apple nor Google have the source code.

For the android app decompiling will yield in partly readable source code. For the iOS app you will end up with assembly code, which unless you have a very talented developer is not much of use.

If the app is written in some hybrid language like Cordove/phonegap then you might be able to get the HTML and javascript form the app. But you will need to setup the project and rebuild the app partly.

You best option will be to contact the developer and the source code. There is not real other option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to get source code from the Apple Developer account. But you can decompile java binary. Anyway i guess it will be not same to original source code.